# fliter doesn't filter

Tags: matlab, filters, wavelet, sound

In this code I try to decompose music from singer sound with `wfilters` but when I hear it it is still mixed where Iam I wrong ?

```
 function s = scale3(q,n)
  p = length(q);
   if p==n 
   s = q;
    else 
    s = resample(q,n,p);
   end
```

the program

```
s = wavread('K:\Khaleel_3aaza (1).wav'); % whatever here

 [l,h] = wfilters('sym2','d');
 [z.x]=wavedec(s,2,l,h);

p = scale3(z.x(2245001:22350000),2245000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background music and human voice occupy the same frequency ranges, so they cannot be separated by filters. See [this Q&A](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/how-to-extract-vocal-part-from-stereo-audio-signal/) for a few suggestions of techniques to separate human voice from background music.

Comment: ok ccan you tell me how I made it less harm full

Comment: waw this good help thanx

Comment: becouse you drict my right I found BSS(blind source separation) it make my work and I found toolbox for it in matlab this it's link as gift http://bass-db.gforge.inria.fr/fasst/