# voice pattern matching algorithm

Tags: matlab, fft, algorithms, sound, voice

My idea is to find a word in wav/mp3 files. It is just one word.
I have a database with a few hundred songs.

I am looking for pattern matching (this is not an exact pattern) it can be an word i choose but only one.

1. Can you recommend a pre-processing algorithm. you run the algorithm on the files?
2. Can you recommend a real-time algorithm?

I have found [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Sound_pattern_matching_using_Fast_Fourier_Transform_in_Windows_Phone) online

Comment: If the word is pronounced with a different voice than your template and/or if there is background music it'll be out of reach with the simple technique you have linked to.

Comment: let us a assume i have 400 songs and i want to find out the word "House". how can i do that?

Comment: This is a hard problem. The first step is to isolate the vocals from the background music. Some pointers: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/how-to-extract-vocal-part-from-stereo-audio-signal/1500#1500. The second step is to identify words - the problem is called "keyword spotting" in the speech recognition community. The fact that the word will be sung rather than spoken makes the problem harder. I doubt you'll get decent performances using even state of the art algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in voice recognition. Check out Hidden markovs model. It is used by several softwares to recognize your words

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement has large amount of data for processing. In order to get the exact pattern matching, Artificial Neural Networks/Adaptive Neuro Fuzzy Inference System tool can be used for training this large amount of data and the network will optimize the result while testing.